# How would you make an RSS-feeds entries available longer than they're accessible from the source?

Tags: caching, rss, offline, podcast

My computer at home is set up to automatically download some stuff from RSS feeds (mostly torrents and podcasts). However, I don't always keep this computer on. The sites I subscribe to have a relatively large throughput, so when I turn the computer back on it has no idea what it missed between the the time it was turned off and the latest update.

**How would you go about storing the feeds entries for a longer period of time than they're available on the actual sites?**

I've checked out Yahoo's pipes and found no such functionality, Google reader can sort of do it, but it requires a manual marking of each item. Magpie RSS for php can do caching, but that's only to avoid retrieving the feed too much not really storing more entries.

I have access to a webserver (LAMP) that's on 24/7, so a solution using a php/mysql would be excellent, any existing web-service would be great too.

I could write my own code to do this, but I'm sure this has to be an issue previously encountered by someone?

**What I did:**
I wasn't aware you could share an entire tag using Google reader, thanks to Mike Wills for pointing this out. 
Once I knew I could do this it was simply a matter of adding the feed to a separate Google account (not to clog up my personal reading list), I also did some selective matching using Yahoo pipes just to get the specific entries I was interested in, this too to minimize the risk that anything would be missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Google Reader for my podiobooks.com subscriptions. I add all of the feeds to a tag, in this case podiobooks.com, that I share (but don't share the URL). I then add the RSS feed to iTunes. [Example here](http://www.google.com/reader/shared/user/12209278408903133361/label/podiobooks.com).

Comment: I'll be damned, I wasn't aware I could share entire tags. I'll definitely look into this!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [Google Reader](http://reader.google.com) does everything you're wanting.  Not sure what you mean by marking individual items--you'd have to do that with any RSS aggregator.

Comment: Google reader doesn't make any of your feeds available to the public except for your shared items, that's what I mean by "marking". 
But I might be able to figure out a way to log into Google reader from a script...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want some sort of service that checks the RSS feed every X minutes, so you can download *every* single article/item published to the feed while you are "watching" it, rather than only seeing the items displayed on the feed when you go to view it. Do I have that correct?

Instead of coming up with a full-blown software solution, can you just use cron or some other sort of job scheduling on the webserver with whatever solution you are already using to read the feeds and download their content?

Otherwise it sounds like you'll end up coming close to re-writing a full-blown service like Google Reader.

Comment: the feeds are read by "regular" programs like uTorrent, so I'd like it to be transparent to them. What I'm after is this "full blown" solution, but rather a minimal bare bones version of it, just storing all new entries and making them available for a longer time.

Answer (score -1):

Writing an aggregator for keeping longer history shouldn't be too hard with a good RSS library.

Comment: No, I'm sure it wont, I just figure someone's bound to have done it before and hopefully made the code available saving me the trouble.

Comment: First: This is a programming site. Doing this really is quite simple and it gives some flexibility over existing solutions. Second: It is nice to have alternatives for Google.